# Run python-selenium script through jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I have a selenium script written in Python, how do I run it through jmeter?

I read it from other posting that you can choose JSR223 sampler, but it really does not have in language portion, a choice of python.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [jython](https://www.programmersought.com/article/4714534237/) jar and copy it to JMeter's lib folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible via JSR223 Sampler, although you can get Python language support in JSR223 test elements by putting [Jython jar](https://www.jython.org/download.html) to the [JMeter classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you [won't be able to install selenium module](https://www.jython.org/jython-old-sites/faq3.html)

So the options are in:

1. Use [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) for launching your Python scripts
2. Convert your Python scripts into "pure" JMeter scripts by running them via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), see [Http proxies](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/) Selenium documentation chapter for example code

Comment: Dmitri, thanks so much for replying. I am learning on how to use option 1 from above - OS Process Sampler. However, have issue.

Comment: (apparently, I can not add an attachment of screenshots)

Comment: I have :  command : /Users/pchao/Desktop/venv/bin/python

Comment: Ask another question instead of adding comments to already resolved issue